# Camera with special feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, algorithm

I am interested in implementing a camera feature within a React Native application. Specifically, I would like the camera interface to include a framing element, allowing the user to capture an image only within the confines of this frame. It is crucial that any content outside of this frame is not captured in the image. I am aiming for a camera setup similar to the one used in Google Pay for scanning QR codes. Despite multiple attempts, I have been unsuccessful in achieving this functionality. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or solutions you can provide to help me achieve this goal.

I have many libraries used likes react-native-vision-camera,react-native-camera-kit,react-native-camera but its deprecated

Comment: "Despite multiple attempts, I have been unsuccessful in achieving this functionality" – what's gone wrong? What have you tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ok I will upload zip file

Comment: I have developed a basic code that utilizes the React Native Camera Kit to create a camera interface with a custom frame. Following image capture, I employ the React Native Image Cropper library for further image processing.